# Auto-update app without play store in android

Tags: android

I have tried to make an application that has been updated without the play store.

I already tried to download and install through the apk, but it does not install, because it already has a package installed with the same name.
I tried to create a secondary application, just to update the first one, but when I try to hide the icon, I stop being able to open the application

I have this to install the application

```java
if (outputFile.exists()) {  
   Uri downloaded_apk = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", outputFile);
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(downloaded_apk,"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I unable to understand your views correctly. I think You want to update another app with same package name with some changes without play store. Just uninstall previous app and install your new app.

Comment: I think if want to update and install with with Android Studio.It is very easy just install with USB devices connected with Mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are updating app then in your new apk file you need to increment version code from your `build.gradle` file after that it will directly update that existing apk to new one

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I have a question, I tried with the signed release, the unsigned, and with the unsigned debug, and only the debug works. With the unsigned release it gives package error, and with the signed one it gives the error of the repeated package.

Comment: @Osozzoka update will only work if existing apk and new apk is debug OR

existing apk and new apk is signed apk